# Reference for Multilinear Algebra

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, multilinear-algebra

Can anyone please suggest me a good reference for Multilinear Algebra?
Specifically, I'm looking for the following topics:
Tensor, Symmetric, and Exterior Algebra and their functorial properties; 
Relation between symmetric and exterior algebra.

I need something which discusses these things pretty thoroughly.

Thanks!

Comment: Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Lee John M.

Comment: Multilinear Algebra by Greub.

Comment: I like the Didactics of An Introduction to Manifolds | Loring W. Tu | Springer

Comment: Bourbaki, Algebra I, chapters 1-3.

Comment: In case you're still looking: Multilinear Algebra by Northcott covers exactly what you're asking for, I think. It's terse and dry but very clear.